# How do I parse a JSON string that defines a function

Tags: javascript, json, string-parsing

I have the following string as content in a div.  I want to use JSON.parse to convert this into a JSON object.  When I try it always fails with Unexpeded token.

```js
    let paramstr=document.querySelector('#cart_payment_params').innerText;
    let params=JSON.parse(paramstr);
```

```html
    <div id="cart_payment_params" style="display:none;">{
     style: {
      shape: 'pill',
      color: 'blue',
      layout: 'vertical',
      label: 'paypal'
     },
     createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
       purchase_units: [{
        amount: {
         value: '1'
        }
       }]
      });
     },
     onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
       alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
      });
     }
    }</div>
```

Javascript Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 118
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Can you post the JSON you are trying to parse too?

Comment: Having a function like this is no longer JSON format, so you can not parse it with JSON parsing. JSON supports arrays, objects and primitives types (number, string, boolean, null) only.

Answer (score 0):

robinvrd answered this.  JSON supports arrays, objects and primitives types (number, string, boolean, null) only.